# django model object reuse without erasing data's

Tags: python, html, django, database, model

In my project I conduct one tournament on one date..so users are like to register the tournament..so I store users register info to my database.. Then the another Date I am conducting another tournament but this time I want to store the user info in the same model without erasing the old tournament data's in database.

Because I don't want to create the  new Model for every tournament
Is there any possible ways to do that?

any one help me
thanks advance

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to achieve. Perhaps it is easier by working with some sample data.

Comment: you know about pubg game sir

Answer (score 0):

Then register Users to a User Model and Link the tournaments to the users using ManyToMany Relationship.